# How can i read an image, if it was dragged from another tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I found, that it is possible to read files (images in my case) on dragging from another browser tab (dropbox, google images). 
It is not difficult to read files, that dragged from desktop; but in case of browser tab my event-object in drop function is empty. 
What is the point, how can i get image data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Let's add id="dropbox" to our container. So, the solution is:

```
$('#dropbox').on("drop", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer,
        files = dt.files;
    if(files.length > 0){
        // process files
    }
    else{
        var img = $(dt.getData('text/html'));
        if(img.is('img')){
            console.log( img.attr('src') );
        }
    }
});
```